# How to use COUNTIF with two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I am attempting to count how many rows resulted in the following:

1. Have a "Successful" launch status
2. Have a list size that surpasses the circled area in R10

I know how to simply find which are greater than R10 by using the following formula.

`=COUNTIF(E3:E19, ">" &R10)`

I'm unsure how to add in the Launch Status, "Successful" parameter found in column E.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using COUNTIFS?

Comment: ^^^^^ [See here for more info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't know that was a function. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Why not describe what you did, in the form of an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D3:D19="Success")*(E3:E19>R10))
```

[image]

Comment: OP is asking how to use COUNTIF with more than one criteria,,, better [edit] the post & post some appropriate examples other than SUMPRODUCT !!

Comment: But COUNTIF only work with one criteria, SUMPRODUCT can resolve the problem. Why cannot provide the SUMPRODUCT solution?